# ImportError of a submodule of a module, when running another different module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

I have a structure as

```
name_folder:
    tobeused.py
    name_folder:
          __init__.py
          models.py
          radial.py
```

In module `tobeused.py` I did
`from name_folder import models`.

In module `models.py` I did `from radial import rad` (`rad` is function in `radial.py`)

When I run `models.py` directly, it works. But when I run `tobeused.py` an error shows :

`ImportError: No module named 'radial'`

How to work on this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change 
from radial import rad
to
from .radial import rad

The . allows the file to look locally rather than within the working directory.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But in `models.py` I also actually have `from matplotlib import ...` which works, why this one works?

Comment: This import works because matplotlib is held within python's managed libraries, i.e. the ones installed by pip, whose directory is in the environment path. These can be imported from any location and they will still work, whereas your libraries are local.

Answer (score 1):

add `__init__.py` file to your folder

```
tobeused.py
folder:
      __init__.py
      models.py
      radial.py
```

Detailed explanation : [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

The import :

```
from folder.models import something
```

Comment: Are you sure you can't import it ? I just tested it on https://repl.it/repls/GrimySubduedCallbacks and it seems working. From which directory do you call `tobeused.py` ?

Comment: Edited the Q, the directory is also have same name `name_folder`

Comment: Why is it that way..?

Comment: It's `from package.module import function`, you can also do it like this : `from package import module` then use your module `module.function`

Comment: Thanks @madjaoue.